# How to process retrieved scan result such as loading URLs?

Tags: java, android

I devloped an android app for barcode scanner,now in that i want to carry out further processing on the retrieved scan results, such as loading URLs or looking the data up in a third party data source.So how can i do this.I am using android studio for devloping app.
Here is my code for MAinActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnClickListener {
private Button scanBtn;
private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_button) {
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}

And i am using zxing library.

Here is my edited code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("url");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}

It is the correct way or not?

Comment: Please tell, what library you used for barcode. And it will be great if you could paste your code, how you are using the library.

Answer (score 0):

Start your scanner `Activity` with `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` for processing the retrieved data.

Take a look at the examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: Do you know any example like this..then please tell me.

Comment: Have you checked out the link i've provided? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Yes..but i want to call my service in that app.And i am new in this..so if you know any example then tell....

Answer (score 0):

You have to start new Activity to open your URL.

```
private void openUrl(String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Call this method inside your `onActivityResult` method. Probably `scanContent` variable is your URL.